# Java regex path extraction

Tags: java, regex

I have String in the format:

`String evaluationString = "MATH(($.customString.customString.cuStromString + $.customString.customString)*5% - ($.customString + 5%))"`

I have problem to extract path value ($.string.string or $.string or $.string.string.string) with regex. I need to switch that path with a value from a path
Can someone help?

Comment: Please extend the Problem statement. Desire output, some examples, What you already tried.

Comment: I need to extract part that starts with $ and ends before the mathematical operator. I can not be sure about space between last character of the path and operator

Comment: In this case I need to extract

$.customString.customString.cuStromString
$.customString.customString
$.customString

Comment: @SlobodanVrhovac, what about brackets? Is it also a mathematical operator?

Comment: I need only this part: $.customString.customString.cuStromString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```regex
(\$(?:.\w+)+)
```

It begins matching from $ and includes as many sequences of . followed by letters, numbers, or underscores as necessary. When something else (spaces or operators) appear, the match stops.

Remember to escape the escape character itself by using `\\` when writing this within Java code.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/XaLaXW/1).

Comment: Thats it. Thanks

Comment: @KasperDavidsen, in Java you would have to use a double backslash (`\\\`), since a single backslash is a special character used to espace special characters.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will allow numbers in your identifiers. Depending on your domain, this may or may not be a problem :)

Comment: numbers AND underscores ^_^

Comment: @PavelSmirnov Good point. I guess I have gotten used to my IDE doing this automatically, I don't even think about it. I will make sure it is reflected in the answer.